# Ruby 'strptime()' not raising ArgumentError when passing invalid date format'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I could use some help with an issue I am facing in a Rails project. I am using the strptime function to return a Date object from an inputted string time and target format:

```
date = Date.strptime(date, '%Y-%m')
```

And it seems when I pass in a Date that doesn't match that pattern, i.e. 01-01-24, it does not throw an ArgumentError for me to catch and do anything with. It does catch an invalid input like this: 01-2024 though. Is there a certain kind of validation I can do here to catch this kind of error and check that the RegEx pattern matches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Date#strptime` format is using `'%Y-%m'` as `[year]-[month]` so in the case of `'01-01-2024'` it is seen as `[01]-[01]-2024` and parsed to that date structure.

`strptime` does not respect `%Y` as having a minimum width so your current expression is essentially equivalent to `/\A-?\d+-(?:1[0-2]|0?[1-9])/` (any number of digits followed by a hyphen followed by 1-12 optionally 0 padded)

`'01-2024'` only raises an error because `20` is not a valid month. For Example: `'01-1299'` would not raise an error.

Rather than relying on this naivety, you could validate your "date pattern" using a Regexp e.g.

```
date.match?(/\A\d{4}-(?:1[0-2]|0[1-9])\z/)
```

Comment: That's great! It seems to work, but unfortunately, it's a Ruby 2.4+ method. The `match?`. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: Ruby version 2.2.1

Comment: @KortneyStinson You can use `match` (no question mark)  which is less efficient as it will return a `MatchData` or `=~` which will return the starting position of the match both will function the same as `match?` in a conditional expression. That being said i would recommend updating your ruby 2.2 reached EOL almost 5 years ago

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much @engineersmnky! Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Using pry to investigate with:

```
[22] pry(main)> date = Date.strptime('calimero', '%Y-%m')
Date::Error: invalid date
from (pry):20:in `strptime'
```

it throws a Date::Error exception

Comment: I get this when I run a similar command in Rails console:
date = Date.strptime('01-01-24', '%Y-%m')
 => Sat, 01 Jan 0001